# Marginal distribution - Uniform and Gamma

Tags: probability-distributions

I have the following question:

I need to find the marginal distribution of $Y$, when $X \sim \Gamma (2, \theta)$ and the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is a (continuous) uniform random variable on $[0,x]$. By using the rule that $f_{Y}(y) = \int \limits _{\{x>0\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y) \Bbb dx = \int \limits _{\{x>0\}}f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x) \Bbb dx$ this integral is equal to $\theta$. Is it right and what it means? Is $Y$ degenerate r.v or simply uniform on $[0,\dfrac 1 \theta]$?

Thank you.

Comment: "this integral is equal to θ" Please show in details how you arrive there.

Comment: by solving: $\int_{x>0} \frac{1}{x}\frac{\theta ^2}{\Gamma(2)} e^{-\theta x} x dx = \theta \int_{x>0} \frac{\theta}{\Gamma(2)} e^{-\theta x}  dx$

Comment: You forgot the condition $x>y$ in the integral (which is fortunate, since a constant function cannot integrate to $1$ on $(0,\infty)$...).

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you!

Comment: If you reached a solution, you might want to post it as an answer (and even, after a while, accept it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that from the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ we know that $0\le y \le x$, we have to integrate over $[y, \infty)$, i.e.,
$$
\int_{y}^{\infty} f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x)dx = \int_{y}^{\infty} \theta ^2e^{-\theta x}dx = \theta e^{-\theta y},\,\,\, \forall y\ge 0\, . 
$$